# difficult mysql query wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Could you help me write a difficult query to count count posts on wordpress?

The situation is this:

- There is an ads system on a wordpress web site and search (filtering).
- The home page displays a list of all categories with the number of ads in each of them.
- User enters in the form of city, type of ads and keywords. He can enter all parameters or only one of them.
- The script should display the number of ads in each category.

My script works, but it is very very slow.

```
<?php

 $querystr = "SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = ".$category->cat_ID." AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

$count=0;
foreach($pageposts as $post) { 
setup_postdata($post); 

$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:S');

$validity = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'valid_until', true);

$city = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_location', true);

$action = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_action', true);


$cities = explode("|", $city);

$session_city = $_SESSION["session_city"];

if($_SESSION["session_city"] and !$_SESSION["session_action"] or $_SESSION["session_action"]=='All') {
    if($validity >= $today and in_array($session_city, $cities)) { $count++;}
}

if($_SESSION["session_action"] and !$_SESSION["session_city"] or $_SESSION["session_city"]=='All') {
    if($validity >= $today and $action == $_SESSION["session_action"]) { $count++;}
}

if($_SESSION["session_action"] and $_SESSION["session_city"]) {
    if($validity >= $today and $action == $_SESSION["session_action"] and in_array($session_city, $cities)) { $count++;}
}

if(!isset($_SESSION["session_city"]) and !isset($_SESSION["session_action"])) {
    if($validity >= $today) { $count++;}
}


}

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Other than removing the evil 'SELECT *', there's not much that can be done with this query. Presumably everything is properly indexed? What does the EXPLAIN say?

Comment: Isn't the count simply equal to the number of rows returned?

Comment: slow part when i count ads with php using foreach.

Comment: You have profiled it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about optimization of working code, it is more suited for [codereview.se] or [dba.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_term_taxonomy needs INDEX(taxonomy, term_id)
wp_term_relationships needs INDEX(term_taxonomy_id, object_id)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_term_relationships`; I suspect it is not optimally defined.  (I assume it is a many-to-many relationship between the other two tables?)

If possible, provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

[Cookbook on building indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).